# Show equivalence of the codes

Tags: coding-theory

Let $\mathbb{A}=\{A, B, C\}$ be an alphabet

and

$\mathcal{C}=\{AAC,ABC,ACB,BCB\}$

$\mathcal{D}=\{AAB, ABB, BAA, BAC\}$

are codes

> Prove that $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent

I should find operations that would transform $\mathcal{C}$ into $\mathcal{D}$, however i have no idea how to solve this problem in a clever way, not just checking all the possibilities

Regards

Comment: Avoid no-clue questions.

Comment: What is the definition of equivalence in this application? Same number of words of the same lengths? There is a permutation of $(A,B,C)$ that changes $\mathcal C$ into $\mathcal D$?